# Error en ordenamiento de datos Pseudocodigo PSEINT

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Necesito recibir 5 valores. Posteriormente quiero ordenarlos de menor a mayor y mostrarlos  concatenados en una cadena separada por comas.

Este código no me está dando el resultado esperado:

```
Algoritmo ordenar
Definir num Como Entero
Dimension num(5)
Definir i Como Entero
Definir resultado Como Caracter


Para i=1 hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    //num(i)=azar(50)
    Leer num(i)
FinPara

Para i=1 hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    n=1
    Para j=1 hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        si num(i) >= num(n) Entonces
            n=j
        FinSi
    FinPara

    n1=num(i)
    num(i)=num(n)
    num(n)=n1

FinPara
Escribir "ARREGLO"
Escribir ""

Para i=1 hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    valor=ConvertirATexto(num(i))
    Escribir num(i)
    resultado = resultado + "," + valor
FinPara
Escribir "VALORES: ",resultado
FinAlgoritmo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa sobre "método de la burbuja" es de los primeros algoritmos que se tienen que aprender :D

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede con tu código es que en la primer iteración del ciclo Para `resultado` es igual a NADA, así que a NADA le estás agregando `, + valor` por eso te aparece primero una coma en lugar de un número. Una solución pasa por inicializar la variable resultado para que eso no pase:

**Antes de comenzar con la iteración deberías inicializar `resultado = ConvertirATexto(num(1))` y comenzar el ciclo con `i = 2`**

```
resultado = ConvertirATexto(num(1))
Para i = 2 hasta 5 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    valor=ConvertirATexto(num(i))
    Escribir num(i)
    resultado = resultado + "," + valor
```

---